# Don't show first line with common key bindings in mutt's menus

Tags: configuration, mutt

In the usual message index, mutt uses one line for displaying

```
 q:Quit  d:Del  u:Undel  s:Save  m:Mail  r:Reply  g:Group  ?:Help
```

Similar key bindings are displayed in other menus, e.g in the attachment menu, and so on.

This is helpful when starting out with mutt, but after a while this line isn't all that useful anymore.

> Is there a way to turn this menu and use this line of screen real estate for an extra message, an extra attachment, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the help line. It can be toggled on or off with `:set help`.

You can have mutt start with it off with a setting in your `muttrc`:

```
unset help
```

If you would like to have the option to toggle it back on from time to time (rather than using the command), you can bind it to a key:

```
macro index,pager <F2> ":toggle help<enter>:set ?help<enter>"  "toggle help status line"
```

Now, hitting <kbd>F2</kbd> will toggle it on and off as required.

Comment: Perfect. Once you know the name, the rest is clear. Thanks!